# How dependencies affect Firebase Functions cold start?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cold-start

**Background:** I have about 20 Firebase Cloud Functions and they are stored under the default `reporoot/functions/src/` folder, which was created when I first init the Firebase project. Each Cloud Function could have its own unique dependencies and all are specified inside one single `reporoot/functions/package.json`

**Simplified version of the scenario:**

1. In the `package.json`, I specify *dependencies* Lib**A**, Lib**B** and **dev**Dpendencies Lib**X**
2. In `reporoot/functions/src/myFeatureSet1/feature1.ts`, I have a CloudFunction1 by `import functionA from LibA`
3. In `reporoot/functions/src/myFeatureSet2/feature2.ts`, I have a CloudFunction2 by `import functionB from LibB`

**Questions:**

1. If I deploy CloudFunction1 to Firebase, will Lib**A**, Lib**B** and Lib**X** be packaged together in the same deployment zip? Or only Lib**A** will be included in the package to be deployed because that is the only library referred by CloudFunction1 in `reporoot/functions/src/myFeatureSet1/feature1.ts`?
2. Will the number of dependencies impact the cold start time of **all** functions developed with the same `package.json` under `reporoot/functions/src/`? Or the deployed Cloud Function will have only what it needs without extra dependencies included?
3. Similar to the Question 2 above, how about **dev**Dependencies? Will the number of **dev**Dependencies impact the cold start time of **all** functions developed with the same `package.json` under `reporoot/functions/src/`? I think deploying the Cloud Function associates `npm i --production` and hence will not include **dev**Dependencies. Is that true?
4. If the answer for Q2/Q3 above is Yes, how can I split the dependencies among different functions so that each function packages with only the required dependencies? I read https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#managing_multiple_source_packages_monorepo and it shows different `package.json` files for different codebase. But following that leads to the following error when I start using the emulator:
   **functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'axios'**. *Note: One of my Cloud Function uses axios and I put it inside one `package.json`*
5. Will there be any code start time difference if I `import functionA from LibA` VS `import * from LibA`?

Comment: You've got a lot of questions here that may already be covered by these threads: [Should I split my packages for FF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70920991/3068190) and [How to optimize cold starts for FF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66813496/3068190)

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks for you links. Unfortunately, even though they are good information, they address different scenario and are not tacking the concern in the situation I have...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following assumes your `index.ts` is similar to:

```js
export functionA from LibA
export functionB from LibB
```

and each function is similar to:

```js
export default functions.https.onRequest(/* ... */);
```

> 1. If I deploy CloudFunction1 to Firebase, will Lib**A**, Lib**B** and Lib**X** be packaged together in the same deployment zip?

As LibA and LibB are true dependencies, they will be installed when deployed. As LibX is in `devDependencies`, it will be skipped.

However, if the source code of LibA, LibB and LibX are all inside the `reporoot/functions` folder, they will all get deployed, but not necessarily executed (that would depend on your code).

> 2. Will the number of dependencies impact the cold start time of **all** functions developed with the same `package.json` under `reporoot/functions/src/`? Or the deployed Cloud Function will have only what it needs without extra dependencies included?

By default, dependencies **will** affect the cold start of all functions.

There are some ways you can structure your code to mitigate this, as covered in [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/9261ee8450f0), [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66813496/3068190) or by using a library like [`better-firebase-functions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-firebase-functions).

You could also compile your code into many bundles, deploying a single bundle of each function, containing only that function and its dependencies. You'd do this using deploy scripts similar to those covered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65535935/3068190). This strategy can get messy if not properly thought out.

> 3. Similar to the Question 2 above, how about **dev**Dependencies?

As deployed functions are considered a production environment, you are correct in that `devDependencies` will not be installed in the production environment.

> 4. How can I split the dependencies among different functions so that each function packages with only the required dependencies?

One of the best approaches to achieve this is to export each function in its own `functionX.ts` file (preferably with an accurate name). You can then compile these as standalone bundles, invoke them using lazy loading or group them together with other similar functions. See the resources linked above for further details.

If `axios` is used by only one function, either spin that function off into its own file/bundle or import it using `(await import('axios')).default` when you need it. The error you get suggests that one of your libraries tries to import the `axios` library at the top of the file, but when that library gets imported by a non-`axios` function (where it's omitted from the `package.json` file), it causes a deploy error.

I would personally use either `node-fetch-native`, `node-fetch` or `gaxios` (a `node-fetch`-based variant of the `axios` APIs, used internally to the Firebase libs) instead.

> 5. Will there be any code start time difference if I `import functionA from LibA` VS `import * from LibA`?

Based on just that line, it's hard to tell. It would depend on the contents of your library and the build tool you are using. The default compiler will just convert your TypeScript to plain JavaScript regardless of whether its used or not. Whereas if your build tool supports "tree shaking", it will only compile what it needs ignoring the unnecessary "leaves" (unused code). Popular tree shaking tools include Webpack and Rollup.

Comment: Bravo @samthecodingman! This is the best answer I have seen! Very detailed and clear and it's even better than the official response I got from Google Support! If I may just ask one more question on this topic: Should I use `import { https } from "firebase-functions";` instead of 'import * as functions from "firebase-functions";'? I am using the default setup from Firebase, so I am not sure if they tree shaking when building the code.

Comment: @CupidChan The default build step doesn't do any tree shaking so that import statement won't matter in that regards. However, the exposed parts of the `firebase-functions` package are components of builder classes that are meant to be chained together. e.g. `functions.https.onRequest` is clearer than `https.onRequest`, and is even clearer when specifying the region and other settings such as in `functions.region("europe-west1").https.onRequest` vs. `region("europe-west1").https.onRequest`.

Comment: i have just did @samthecodingman. But it's still clear regarding to your previous comment about the advantage of importing only the specific component `import { https } from "firebase-functions";` VS everything `import * from "firebase-functions";` is there any performance gain by doing so? Or it's pure a clearer approach for developer to see what exactly being imported?

Answer (score 0):

**Update as of Firebase Functions' new codebase feature**

Firebase Functions now have a `codebase` [configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=1st#managing_multiple_source_packages_monorepo_2) that allows you to define (and deploy) separate codebases for grouping functions, each with its own dependencies.

This allows you to:

1. Set separate `package.json` files for each codebase and reduce overall size thus reducing cold starts.
2. You can actually use different platforms (node js, python) for each codebase
3. Deploy each codebase separately, deploy each function within each codebase separately, and deploy all functions in all codebases if you please.

This allowed us to easily create a functions gen2 codebase to deploy alongside our existing gen1 functions w/o any need to migrate code or environment for gen1.