# how to manage different firebase functions that require their own dependencies?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

**Background**

My project has around 10 Firebase functions which are defined in `index.ts`. Every function requires its own dependency so I've added all 10 dependencies into `package.json`. It works fine as of now but, I see a few problems with this in the future. First, dependency conflicts. Second, every function will load unnecessary dependencies. Third, it's simply not clear to read. The project is planning to have around 100 functions...

The project structure now:

```
firebase-project/
  firebase.json
  functions/
    package.json
    src/
      index.ts
```

I want to isolate every function with its own dependency manager (`package.json`).

Here are some solution I've considered!

1. Using npm workspace

   I tried to do something like this:

   ```
   firebase-project/
     firebase.json
     functions/
       package.json
       src1/
         package.json
         function1.ts
       src2/
         package.json
         function2.ts
   ```

   The problem is, that this creates multiple entry points. I have no clue how to set different entry points for every function. (maybe it's possible to import it into a single index.ts entry point but this defeats the whole purpose of splitting it so I'm not looking into importing it into one file.)
2. Using codebase

   I've read this [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=2nd#managing_multiple_repositories). If I go this approach I have to create a Firebase project for every function. (which I find it's overkill)
3. Using codebase (monorepo)

   This is mentioned in this [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=2nd#managing_multiple_source_packages_monorepo). But I have no clue if this is what I'm looking for. This Firebase project structure is not what I'm familiar with and I tried to search sample codes on other websites but had no luck.

   Project structure:

   ```
   firebase-project/
     firebase.json
     functions/
       firebase.json
       function1/
         index.ts
         package.json
       function2/
         index.ts
         package.json
   ```
4. Using the good old Cloud Functions (not Firebase Functions)

   I know this approach works. This [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-functions-best-practices-1-4-get-the-environment-ready-af666af89f62) explains it extremely well. But I have to implement my own Firebase auth etc and have to make a different repo to my Firebase project. (I already use other Firebase services). This is the last solution I'm going to resort to.

**What I want to achive**

I want to have a project structure like 4, but use Firebase functions. It looks like 3 is what I'm looking for but I don't understand how the document is structuring the project. I want to know the whole folder structure from the root of the Firebase project.

Comment: It looks like you know your options, and which things actually work. What is your question?  If you're looking for an opinion about what's best, that's off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Questions are required to show that code that's not working as expected, or have some clear problem statement.

Comment: I made it clear what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: The documentation you linked for #3 shows an example of the directory structure you're supposed to use.  What you're showing doesn't match the documentation at all (there is no "functions" parent folder). Why don't you first try duplicating exactly what the documentation shows and get that to work first?

Comment: Sounds like you need a mix of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65535935/3068190) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66815121/3068190).